# How to quickly find the vue instance in the window object

Tags: vue.js, web, vuejs2

[image]

This is a website developed using the vue front-end framework. I printed the window object on the console, trying to find an instance of vue, how to find it quickly？

I want to analyze the website developed by other people with vue, not the website developed with vue by myself~~~

Answer (score 2):

You could access it with:

- `__VUE_DEVTOOLS_INSTANCE_MAP__` (no need for `window`)
- by using the [devtools for VueJS v2](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd) (if using v3, it's [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/ljjemllljcmogpfapbkkighbhhppjdbg?hl=en)), selecting the `root` component and then accessing it in
  the console with `$vm0`
- select an element in your `Elements` tab and then `$0.__vue__`, kudos to Markus Oberlehner's [tweet](https://twitter.com/MaOberlehner/status/1372160086848716800)

[image]

Also, [Vue Telescope](https://vuetelescope.com/) is a nice extension too (gives some cool details on the packages used) !

Comment: oh，thank you so much !!!! [Vue.js is detected on this page.Devtools inspection is not available because it's in production mode or explicitly disabled by the author.] ，I want to analyze the website developed by other people with vue, not the website developed with vue by myself

Comment: I've edited my answer. Beyond those methods, I don't think that you can simply access this kind of stuff. It's a bit the point to not being able to reverse-engineer it too simply. :)

Comment: Edited again to add vue telescope.